# keep getting a syntax error for my for-loop statement? how should i define "mylist"

Tags: loops, for-loop, syntax-error, iterable, iterated-function

I keep getting a syntax error for my for-loop statement and i can't figure out why it keeps saying invalid syntax.

```
> mylist = [1, 2, 3,4 , 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
> for num in mylist
>     print(num)
```

Comment: You're missing a colon at the end of the `for` line.

Comment: Thank you :) im new to python so this is gonna be rough haha

Comment: You'll get through it. I'd also recommend an IDE like Pycharm which will give better hints as to what the problem is.